# String enclosed with double quotes splitting issue

Tags: java

I have a String in the below format.

```
"test","2, High Street, 50100 Eastleigh",",UK"
```

when i split the above string using below code

```
String[] lineArr = line.split("\",", -1)
```

**Actual output is:**

```
"test
"2, High Street, 50100 Eastleigh

UK"
```

**Expected Output is:**

```
test
2, High Street, 50100 Eastleigh
,UK
```

How do i handle this?

Comment: if that's your expected output... what output _are_ you getting?

Comment: I'm sure if i have any escape character before the ' and " in between the column values, i can handle that. without escape character how do i handle this ?

Comment: @Shankar shouldn't it be the other way round ? ->  ",\\""

Comment: `line.split("\",");` will give you `2` if you are taking input from user while if you are using string you have to escape double quotes in between

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] to explain what you have and what you expect with a specific set of data (and the source of the data)

Comment: I have updated my question, please look into this.

Comment: what i answered applies to this situation as well. read it

Comment: @AxelH: my expected output is in the question, not removing the empty cell, it should split in way which return three elements in the array. The above code returns empty cell which is wrong.

Comment: _The above code returns empty cell which is wrong._ but you said **in the same comment** _not removing the empty cell_ make up your mind !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split(String match, int limit)`

If limit is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If limit is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

`"test","2, High Street, 50100 Eastleigh","`

Here when you apply `lineArr.split("\",",-1)`, limit is negative, it will return trailing empty strings as well,

`test`, `"2, High Street, 50100 Eastleigh` and `empty string ""`, Hence giving you `3` as length.

However if you use `lineArr.split("\",",0)` or `lineArr.split("\",")` no trailing empty strings are returned. So you will be getting `2` as length.

To eliminate in between empty strings i would recommend you to use `lineArr.split("\",");` which is `split(String match)`version of above `split method`

According to your output you should call `lineArr.split("\",\"");`, this will give your  resultant output.

Comment: updated my answer as well plz look into this too. :-)

Comment: obviously both negative and zero limit will give same result in this case hence i recommended other version of method

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the first and last `"`, and split on `","`, as follows:

```
String[] lineArr = line.substring(1,line.length()-1).split("\",\"");
```

I am sure there are more efficient and elegant solutions, but this should be an easy adaptation of your code with an one-liner.

Comment: I have just noticed the place of the comma, doing my update I end up with the exact solution ...